# Laravel 5.4 Validator - Show the wrong value passed

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Is there a way to insert, in the **validator** message, the wrong value passed from user?

**UPDATE**:

For example, If the field must accept a value from "1" to "10" and you insert "200" I'd like to write: 
`'The :attribute must be between 1 and 10. Your value is 200.'`:

```
$validator_default_message = [
    'digits_between'  => 'The ":attribute" must be between :min and :max.',
];
$validator = Validator::make($phase, [
                'depth'     => 'digits_between:0,10',
            ], $validator_default_message);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                $status = $validator->failed();
                $errorMessage = $validator->messages()->all();            
                abort($status, $errorMessage);
            }
```

And I'd like to return the message:`The depth must be between 0 and 10. Your input value is 200`.

Thank you.

Comment: not getting what do you need

Comment: Do you want to return the fields that did not pass validation?

Comment: You **do not** return the value, on validation fails messages. What if the value is meant to break your code? Do you really wish to keep it and print out? What if it's a script? Your page might break. You return only message and fill the input fields back in with blade methods.

Comment: Yes, true!!! But in debug mode It could be useful to understand the wrong input value.

Comment: @DainisAbols Could you not return the error message and display the error `{{$error . ' ' . old('value')}}` You escape the html characters so an xss attack should not be possible. Thus it would be only dangerous if echoing the values within `{!! !!}` since it does not escape html.

Comment: @vlauciani log the requests on validation fails

Comment: @milo526 there is always a way to bypass it, that's why you simply don't do it. You don't know what the user will input. Remember this: MY FACE MY FACE ᵒh god no NO NOO̼O​O NΘ stop the an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Comment: @DainisAbols While this may break the layout of the page it is not 'dangerous', If you properly escape the character the script execution you mentioned will not be possible. Furthermore, since you do not retrieve saved values any possible attack will only be for the request which the user will have to have inputted (or be inputted by a malicious script from another exploit)

Answer (score 1):

inside Request file add :

```
    public function messages()
    {
    return [
        'input_name.numeric' => 'your massage'

      ];
    }
```

for more info check here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#customizing-the-error-messages

Comment: Thank you, but I do not want to customise the output errore message; I'd like to return the wrong input field! For example, If the field must accept a value from "1" to "10" and you input "200" I'd like to write: 'The :attribute must be between 1 and 10. Your value is 200.'

Comment: 'input_name.numeric' => 'The xxxx must be between 1 and 10. Your value is '.$request->get('input_name');

Answer (score 1):

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'fieldname.numeric' => 'The :attribute must be numeric. Your value is '.$request->input('fieldname')
    ];
 }
```

Comment: @vlauciani, doesn't his answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'title.required' => 'A title is required',
        'body.required'  => 'A message is required',
    ];
}

so basically the rule of the game is 
return [
yourFieldName.ValidationRule => Customessage
]

and $request->input('fieldname') to access the value
```

this is an example taken from laravel doc

Comment: This does not answer OP's question, op specifically asked to include the old value in the error message. Furthermore this code does not help even with changing the message since it is unclear where you have to put this code or how to use it. If you take information from documentation you might want to include the relevant link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This might offer you more insight:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-custom-error-messages

That messages() method can be put on here: app/Http/Requests/YourRequest.php

From @Laracasts:

Using Laravel 5 .4 and saw that the validate() method optionally accepts the messages[] as its third argument and did this.

```
$this->validate($request,
    [
        'document_date_created' => 'required',
        'document'              => 'required'
    ],
    [
        'document_created_at.required' => 'Sample message',
        'document.required'            => 'Another Sample Message'
    ]
);
```

Comment: This does not answer OP's question, op specifically asked to include the old value in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an instance of a `Validator` on which you used the `validate()` method, it will return back to the page with the old values which can be retrieved by using `old('form field')` i.e. `old('title')`

In your view you can check if you have an error message for a specific field and rule by using:

```
if($errors->has('input_name.numeric')){
    //code
)
```

Here you could use the old input value to return a message:

```
{{$errors->get('input_name.numeric').
  ' Your value was ' . old('input_name') . '.'}}
```

This will print for example:

> The input_name must be between 1 and 10. Your value was 200.

Documentation about retrieving old input can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#old-input).

Comment: Thank you, It could be a good starting point for my problem; I'm working on API RESTful service, so I do not have view page but only output JSON.

Comment: You could also use `$request->old('field');` in your controller to get the same value